# Is there a SQL Wait Cursor?

Tags: .net

I noticed that in Delphi, there is a SQL Wait Cursor where it shows an hourglass with the letters SQL underneath it.

Is there a similar one available in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default. You can set up a custom cursors, but by default .Net only exposes the cursors configured in windows.